# Sticky pagination on dataTables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

i just installed dataTables on a bootstrap based project i am working on. Everything works like a charm so far. I am trying to style some things to follow our existing layout and what i actually trying to succeed is to keep footer under (below) table but also make it stick on bottom of content.

All examples i have seen so far follow same process, pagination is following table height according to number of rows. I need to make it stick on the bottom of page, no matter how many rows are in table.

Thanks in advance,
C

Comment: have you got the html for the footer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply just move the content of the dataTable-footer to your own sticky footer.  Example :

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

when initializing :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable();
$("#example_info").detach().appendTo('#footer');
$("#example_paginate").detach().appendTo('#footer');
```

[image]

All elements created by dataTables gets an id on the form *table id*+`_some name`. You are not delivering any code example, so I can only guess what you have in your footer.

see the above in this fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/tPxD6/**